# gcc -print-prog-name=??? doesn't work as I would expect

Tags: gcc, g++

if I understand the gcc manuals right than the option `-print-prog-name` should print the name of the program used.

But it seems that this option only echoes the given argument

Examples:

```
gcc -print-prog-name=ld
--> ld

gcc -print-prog-name=xxxsome-funny-name
--> xxxsome-funny-name
```

Is this the expected behaviour? I think it should print something like

```
gcc -print-prog-name=ld
--> /usr/bin/ld

gcc -print-prog-name=xxxsome-funny-name
--> unknown program
```

EDIT: testing on Debian Lenny 64bit with gcc v4.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the -print-prog-name option only applies to a small set of tools that GCC 
uses internally.  For example,

```
$ gcc -print-prog-name=cc1
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/cc1

$ ls -L /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/
cc1  cc1plus  collect2  f771  jc1  jvgenmain
$ gcc -print-prog-name=f771
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/f771
```

So `gcc -print-prog-name` is aware of the tools that live in that directory.  But:

```
$ gcc -print-prog-name=ld
ld
```

My guess is that if `gcc -print-prog-name` returns an absolute path, it's configured
to use that version of the program, no matter what's on your $PATH -- otherwise
it just echoes back what you gave it without resolving it to an absolute pathname.

Comment: To add, ld is a part of binutils, NOT GCC. So GCC just invokes it as an external program instead of a known place (which is why you get a global path instead of direct one)

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found another reason for the behaviour of

```
gcc -print-prog-name=ld
```

The `ld` command is not invoked directly by gcc.

gcc invokes `collect`. And it is `collect` which in turn invokes ld.